Nginx: net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR with React on Port 3000 and Node.js on Port 5000
I'm experiencing an issue with my Nginx setup that results in a net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR. My setup involves a React frontend running on port 3000 and a Node.js backend running on port 5000.
The Nginx server is handling HTTPS traffic and I have configured it to proxy the frontend and backend requests. Here is my Nginx configuration:
server {
    # Redirect HTTP to HTTPS
    listen 80;
    server_name lisansyayincilik.com.tr www.lisansyayincilik.com.tr;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

server {
    # HTTPS settings
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name lisansyayincilik.com.tr www.lisansyayincilik.com.tr;

    # SSL certificates
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/lisansyayincilik.com.tr/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/lisansyayincilik.com.tr/privkey.pem;
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf;
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem;

    # TLS Protocols (only declared once)
    ssl_protocols TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;

    ssl_session_cache shared:MozSSL:10m;
    ssl_stapling on;
    ssl_stapling_verify on;

    # Proxy configuration for React frontend
    location / {
        root /var/www/lisansyayincilik/ly_frontend/build;
        index index.html;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html =404;
    }

    # Proxy configuration for Node.js backend
    location /api/ {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:5000;  # Backend running on port 5000
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;

        # CORS headers
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' 'https://www.lisansyayincilik.com.tr';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'Authorization, Content-Type, Accept';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true';

        # Preflight requests
        if ($request_method = OPTIONS) {
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' 'https://www.lisansyayincilik.com.tr';
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS';
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'Authorization, Content-Type, Accept';
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true';
            return 204;
        }
    }

    # WebSocket setup (optional)
    location /socket.io/ {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:5000/socket.io/;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
    }
}


Whenever I send a request to my backend API, I get the following error in the browser console:
net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR

I ensured that the SSL certificates are valid and correctly installed.
CORS headers have been added to the Nginx configuration for the /api/ location.
The backend Node.js server works when accessed directly on port 5000 using HTTP, but not through HTTPS via the Nginx proxy.
How can I fix the net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR when making requests to my Node.js backend through Nginx? Is there something wrong with the Nginx configuration or the proxy setup for the backend?
Any help or insight into this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Accessing https://lisansyayincilik.com.tr/api/ gives for me a 404 but not a SSL protocol error. I suspect that you use https://lisansyayincilik.com.tr:5000/api/, i.e. with the port 5000. This is wrong since this does not access the backend through nginx and thus also does not make use of the SSL provided by nginx. Apart from that it is a bad idea to expose the backend directly, bypassing the nginx reverse proxy.
